# VISA Debit card refund on another currency

Tags: currency, refund, visa, foreign-currency

What happens when a VISA Debit refund is issued with a currency that's different than the account tied to that card? In detail:

- Merchant charges PLN.
- Charge gets converted to EUR and gets deducted from account. It was pending for a few days.
- Few days later merchant issues a reversal with the amount in PLN, which is confirmed.

There is no PLN account tied to the card. No refund has shown up in almost 3 weeks. What are my options other than wait and hope?

Comment: Have you asked your bank about it?

Comment: In the end, they figured it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The refund will be in the same currency that it was charged in.**

When making a charge, the merchant specifies an amount and a currency. That is converted to the currency of the card, using the appropriate exchange rate for the day it was converted, and that is debited to the card account.

When a refund is made, that amount refunded is converted (again) to the card currency and that amount is credited to the card. This does mean that the amount refunded can be different from the amount charged, in card currency.